# Java search object by string

Tags: java, object

I have a class Item
And create multiple objects (tree, tv, book. etc)
in the class Game

```
    // Create the items
    tree            = new Item("tree", "I big green tree", 60);
    coat            = new Item("coat", "I white coat", 5);
    paper           = new Item("paper", "a role of wc paper", 1);
```

Now a player (also playerclass) must save some items.
The player can get this item by typing: get book, where book is the String secondWord.

Now i need a function in the class Game that can get
a object by a string.

For example;

The player enters take book.

```
player1.takeItem(Item secondWord);
```

and in the class player i have this function takeItem()

```
/**
 * Method to take item
 * and add them to the ArrayList carriedItems
 * @param secondCommandWord is the second word command
 * Ex: take book -> book is then command
 */
public void takeItem(Item secondCommandWord)
{
    // Add new item to carried list
    carriedItems.add(secondCommandWord);
}
```

But this doesn't work. Hope you could help me

Comment: Please show us some code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your class `Item` looks like this:

```
public class Item {

    private String kind;
    private String description;
    private int price;

    public Item(String kind, String description, int price) {
        this.kind = kind;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, in the `Item` class, you can simply make a method which returns the kind of the item as a String.

```
public String getKind() {
    return this.kind;
}
```

I guess you have a list of all items somewhere. Then you can easily get the item from the list using `getItem(String)`, which returns the desired item.

```
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>() {{
    add(new Item("tree", "I big green tree", 60));
    add(new Item("coat", "I white coat", 5));
    add(new Item("paper", "a role of wc paper", 1));
}};

public Item getItem(String itemName) {
    for (Item item : this.items) {
        if (item.getKind().equals(itemName)) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```